# Use abstract Spring bean as constructor-arg

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, constructor-injection, spring-ioc

We have a hierarchy of handler classes in our codebase which implement a kind of chain-of-responsibility principle. There is an abstract parent class and it is extended by several child classes, which also receive the abstract in their constructor

```
public abstract class AbstractHandler {
  public AbstractHandler(final AbstractHandler next, final PropertyName propertyName) {
    this.next = next;
    this.propertyName = propertyName;
  }
  ...  

public class OneConcreteChildHandler extends AbstractHandler {
  public OneConcreteChildHandler(final AbstractHandler next) {
    super(next, PropertyName.OneConcreteChild);
  }
  ...
```

We would now need to inject an instance of one of the concrete child classes into a newly implemented service class, and we should configure this in XML. We can configure an abstract bean for the abstract parent class, but this one then does not seem to be allowed to be used as constructor-arg for the concrete child bean

```
<bean id="abstractHandler" abstract="true" class="...AbstractHandler" />

<bean id="oneConcreteChildHandler" class="...OneConcreteChildHandler" parent="abstractHandler">
    <constructor-arg ref="abstractHandler"/> //"abstract bean can not be used here"
</bean>

<bean id="someService" class="...SomeService">
    <constructor-arg ref="oneConcreteChildHandler"/>
    ...
```

Is there any way to overcome this? The handler class hierarchy is legacy code and we are not able to modify their sources at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that you are trying to inject a abstract bean. You should not do this. This `abstractHandler` should be used just for mapping the `parent` in child bean. Despite, it doesnt seen to be really what you want/need. You wouldn't pass a abstract object in this constructor, but another child class's object. You Chain must have a end point, where the constructor's argument `next` will be null like that:

```
<bean id="abstractHandler" abstract="true" class="...AbstractHandler" />

<bean id="oneConcreteChildHandler" class="...OneConcreteChildHandler" parent="abstractHandler">
        <constructor-arg ref="twoConcreteChildHandler"/>
    </bean>

<bean id="twoConcreteChildHandler" class=".." parent="abstractHandler">
    <constructor-arg name="next">
        <null />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="someService" class="...SomeService">
    <constructor-arg ref="oneConcreteChildHandler"/>
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. We just noticed that among the concrete child classes there is actually an existing TailChildHandler class for the purpose of closing the CoR chain (its constructor contains super(null,null)) and we can utilize it in the config the same way as twoConcreteChildHandler in your example. This resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Spring's abstract bean concept is NOT the same as Java's abstract class concept.

In Java, you cannot instantiate an instance of an abstract class, and therefore trying to map an abstract bean to an abstract java type will not work when it comes time to instantiate it.

I would recommend that you instead look at how [Servlet Filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/interceptingfilter-142169.html) work (via the FilterChain), or [Spring's HandlerInterceptor pattern](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-interceptor-tutorial/).